# TryParse getting annoying

Tags: c#, tryparse

I am having this really annoying issue (I know this is basic stuff) but when I try use tryparse, I have to enter 2 values before it says integer, I want it to say integer after 1 try. (btw I have to use tryparse)
here is an example.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int results = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("how old are you?");
            int.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out results);

            if (int.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out results))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("integer");                 
            }     
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not an integer");     
            }
            Console.ReadLine();      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a variable `string input = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Your code does exactly what you asked it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the first redundant call to `TryParse` e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int results = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("how old are you?");

        //int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out results); <-- remove this

        if (int.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out results))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("integer");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not an integer");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  variables for `Console.ReadLine()` and `int.TryParse`:

```
Console.WriteLine("how old are you?");
string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
bool success = int.TryParse(input, out results);

if ( success )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is an integer", input); // results has the correct value                
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", input);                 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent.

*A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.*

So you can always use it like this.

```
if (int.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out results))
{
    Console.WriteLine("integer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of the other answers you may wish to do the `TryParse` in a `while loop` so that users must enter a valid integer

```
while(!int.TryParse(ConsoleReadLine(), out results)
     Console.WriteLine("not an integer");

ConsoleWriteLine("integer");
```

---

To better explain your current issue, you are asking the user to enter two integers, but you only ever care about the second one. The first one is assigned to `results` but then it is overriden the next time you call `TryParse` without ever being used